# What would happen to the answers if the question was deleted by the original poster?

Tags: feature-request

It is sad to learn that when "the person who posted the question deleted it. That has the effect, indeed, of disappearing question, answers, comments and all into the Memory Hole."

Of course, the original poster has the right to delete his/her post. However, the answers and also the comments are (or could be) valuable to these authors for their future references. May be SE should think about this and do something to protect them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We already have several protections in place:

1. Users cannot delete questions if there is an upvoted answer.
2. Short of contacting the Stackexchange team, users can't "hard-delete" any post; the posts are still visible to users with 10k+ reputation, and can be undeleted by a vote of 3 10k+ users or by a moderator.

I think these protections are sufficient. In a few rare cases a good answer may not get upvoted quickly enough to be saved, but in those cases users can flag the post for a moderator's attention.

Comment: "In a few rare cases a good answer may not get upvoted quickly enough" -- you must be new here. Lots of good answers stay at 0 forever.

Comment: Yes. I am a newcomer but also an enthusiast.

Comment: @PostNoBills In my percentage, it's a small percentage; but perhaps I have a higher bar for "good answer". Coupled with the small percentage of questions with answers that gets deleted, it becomes tiny. And no, I'm not exactly "new" here.